How can i use fscanf from file to struct in c?
I cannot save information of students from file to struct. When I tried to printf my struct its not working.
I think it should work but I dont understand why it is not working. When I did only struct or use file like this it works.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//John exper 224(number) 99(grade)
//Alex King 199 36

struct Student{
    char name[100],surname[100],number[100];
    int grade[100];
};

readStudentsFromFile();
printStudents();
rankStudents();
calculateClassAverage();  

int main (){
    struct Student var[100];
    double co;
    readStudentsFromFile(&co);
}

readStudentsFromFile(double *co){
    char fileName[100],c;
    struct Student var[100];
    int i,count;
    printf("Enter file name: ");    
    gets(fileName);
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen(fileName,"r");
    
    if (file){
    count=1;    
        while(!feof(file))
        {
            c = fgetc(file);
            if(c == '\n')
            {
                count++;
            }
        }   
        for(i=0;i<count;i++){
            fscanf("%s %s %s %d",&var[i].name,&var[i].surname,&var[i].number,&var[i].grade);
        }
        }else{
            printf("Error: Unable to open file %s",fileName);
        }
    *co=count;
    printf("%s",var[1].name);
    fclose(file);
}

I need to save information to struct.

Please explain exactly what is happening, and what you mean by "not working".

You need to learn C18, not pre-standard C.  The function declarations near the top are hopelessly outdated — they need an explicit return type and the prototypes for the arguments.

Welcome to SO. You should always check the return value of fscanf and similar functions. Also, you should read Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?

What is purpose of struct Student var[100]; in main? It is not used.

The first argument to fscanf should be of type FILE *, but you are passing the format string.  The compiler tells you this.

Never ever use the gets function. It's so dangerous that it actually have been removed from the C language. Use fgets instead.

After you've read the number of lines in the file, you have to rewind it to be able to re-read the data into the structure.

As you did not specify what is going wrong, I would just guess, you need to rewind(file); between your while loop and the for loop.

fgetc returns an int, not a char.

I also suggest you use fgets to read the lines of the file, and then use sscanf to parse the line.

Why int grade[100];? Why do you need 100 grades for the student? Especially since you only try to read one.

Using &var[i].name passes a char (*)[100] (pointer to an array of 100 characters) to fscanf() — but the %s conversion specification expects a char *.  See also How to prevent scanf() from causing a buffer overflow in C?

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong

If your compiler did not warn you about passing incorrect parameter types to fscanf, then you should increase diagnostics level. For gcc or clang use -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

There are many things wrong with your code, but the one that seems to be the biggest issue is the incorrect call to fscanf.  The first argument needs to be the FILE *, so change:
fscanf("%s %s %s %d", ...)

to
if (4 == fscanf(file, "%99s %99s %99s %d", ...)) 

Also, it seems very odd to have grade be an array of ints instead of just an int.  The argument to scanf that corresponds to the %d in the format string should be the address of an int.
